# Compute rotation matrix using the magnetic field

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, rotational-matrices, magnetometer

In get rotation matrix value it contains `public static boolean getRotationMatrix (float[] R, float[] I, float[] gravity, float[] geomagnetic)`
Here how can i calculate the `float[] gravity`?
I found a sample of code where it calculate the `orientation` using both `Accelerometer` and `Magnetic field`

```
boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(
   matrixR,
   matrixI,
   valuesAccelerometer,
   valuesMagneticField);

if(success){
SensorManager.getOrientation(matrixR, matrixValues);

double azimuth = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[0]);
double pitch = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[1]);
double roll = Math.toDegrees(matrixValues[2]);

readingAzimuth.setText("Azimuth: " + String.valueOf(azimuth));
readingPitch.setText("Pitch: " + String.valueOf(pitch));
 readingRoll.setText("Roll: "+String.valueOf(roll));
}
```

My questions are :

- Is orientation value is the rotation matrix value?
- If no then how can i implement this code to get the rotation matrix value using magnetic? field?

To get the rotation matrix i use this code

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (timestamp != 0) {
        final double dT = (sensorEvent.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S;
            double magneticX = sensorEvent.values[0];
            double magneticY = sensorEvent.values[1];
            double magneticZ = sensorEvent.values[2];
                        double omegaMagnitude =Math.sqrt(magneticX*magneticX + magneticY*magneticY + magneticZ*magneticZ);

                        if (omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
                            magneticX /= omegaMagnitude;
                            magneticY /= omegaMagnitude;
                            magneticZ /= omegaMagnitude;
        }
                        double thetaOverTwo = omegaMagnitude * dT / 2.0f;
                        double sinThetaOverTwo =Math.sin(thetaOverTwo);
                        double cosThetaOverTwo = Math.cos(thetaOverTwo);
                        deltaRotationVector[0] = (double) (sinThetaOverTwo * magneticX);
                        deltaRotationVector[1] = (double) (sinThetaOverTwo * magneticY);
                        deltaRotationVector[2] = (double) (sinThetaOverTwo * magneticZ);
                        deltaRotationVector[3] = cosThetaOverTwo;


    }
     double[] deltaRotationMatrix = new double[9];
     SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix, deltaRotationVector);
}
```

But the problem is this `getRotationMatrixFromVector` is says undefine for sensor.Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orientation is not a rotation matrix as it only provides you angles related to magnetic North. You can obtain the **rotation matrix** (Direction Cosine Matrix) that will help you to transform coordinates from your device frame to the Earth's frame this way :

[image: DCM from Wikipedia]

*with*

[image: azimuth] 
 = azimuth (radians)

[image: pitch]
 = pitch (radians)

[image: roll]
 = roll (radians)

Comment: Thanks.Look at my 2nd code where i am trying to get the 9 values of the rotation  matrix,Is it the right way to get those values

Comment: It might be. I did that a long time a go, computing the rotation matrix from a vector didn't give me good results (even though I maybe did something wrong). All I know is that the solution I gave you works perfectly (I still use it) and is simple to implement.

Comment: i find the rotation matrix by using this  `if(success){
   SensorManager.getOrientation(matrixR, matrixValues);//code here to display the matrix value`
     where matrixR is the rotation matrix and give me the result.But i do not understand is it using real co-ordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old thread but in case it helps, for Android I think the 3x3 rotation matrix is actually given by a variation of the approved answer.  To be specific, in Android the rotation matrix is

```
     (cosφ cosψ - sinφ sinψ sinθ)     sinφ cosθ     ( cosφ sinψ + sinφ cosψ sinθ)
    -(sinφ cosψ + cosφ sinψ sinθ)     cosφ cosθ     (-sinφ sinψ + cosφ cosψ sinθ)
              -sinψ cosθ                 -sinθ                  cosφ cosθ
```

where

```
    φ = azimuth
    θ = pitch
    ψ = roll
```

which corresponds to the 3x3 Android rotation matrix R[0] to R[8] (matrixR in the question)  via

```
    R[0] R[1] R[2]
    R[3] R[4] R[5]
    R[6] R[7] R[8]
```

Comment: Does not work. Tried it, but unfortunately causes perspective distortions if used with (deprecated) Orientation Sensor.

Comment: @AlexanderPacha I think you've mis-understood something.  These are the formula that Android uses internally, and all they're doing is specifying a 3D rotation matrix.  The only question is, if you use Android's (non-deprecated) functions to calculate Android's version of azimuth, pitch and roll, are these the right formula to calculate Android rotation matrix R[0]...R[8].   Perspective is nothing to do with this.  I still believe that these are the correct formula.

Comment: There is no non-deprecated sensor that returns azimuth, pitch and roll (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values). For which sensor did you use these formulas and where do you have them from?

Comment: @AlexanderPacha With the readings from `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` and `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY` or `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`, you call `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(…)` to get the rotation matrix.  This call gives you the `R[0]…R[8]` as described by my answer here.  There's also an Android call `SensorManager.getOrientation(…)` which takes that rotation matrix `R[0]…R[8]` to give you azimuth, pitch and roll.