# What exactly is a rotation matrix?

Tags: android, sensors

i have come across this code which uses the phones sensors to get the orientation of the device in degrees along the 3 axes... this value is calculated from a 4x4 matrix called rotation matrix.. so i was wondering what kind of data is stored in the rotation matrix ?

the code is similar to the one in this example
[Android: Problems calculating the Orientation of the Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740808/android-problems-calculating-the-orientation-of-the-device)

Comment: it is a transformation matrix: [rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Rotation)

Comment: so what does the values in the matrix represent a vector ?

Comment: There is this thing called google: http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/

Answer (score 7):

The [Wikipedia article about rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) is reasonable.  Basically, the rotation matrix tells you how to map a point in one co-ordinate system to a point in a different co-ordinate system.  In the context of Android sensors, the rotation matrix is telling you how to map a point from the co-ordinate system of the phone (where the phone itself lies in the x-y plane) to the real world North/East/"Gravity-direction" co-ordinate system.

Android uses either 3x3 or 4x4 rotation matrices.  When 4x4, it's the [Quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) representation of a rotation.  For the 3x3 case, in terms of the [Euler Angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Euler_rotations) aximuth, pitch and roll, see [my answer to 'Compute rotation matrix using the magnetic field'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698092/compute-rotation-matrix-using-the-magnetic-field/15794711#15794711) for how those angles are embedded in the rotation matrix (NB: the accepted answer to that question is wrong).

Comment: I know this is old, but just to clarify a point that confused me about this answer: while you can calculate Euler Angles from a 3x3 rotation matrix, the values *in* the 3x3 matrix are not Euler Angles and can be used as a straight forward rotation matrix, if that's what you're going for.